# drag and drop in unity, drag behind other UI elements

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a Panel with a `Grid Layout Group` component. Inside I got a panel called slot with a background image and inside this I got a prefab of 2 images. it looks like this:
[image: how the grid layout group looks]
I wrote a drag and drop script that found in the `TankPrefab`:

```
public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {
    public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
    Vector3 startPosition;
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;   
    }
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

I have a problem when I drag a tank over a slot that found after the tank's slot. it draw the tank behind him: 
[image: the problem]
I tried `transform.SetAsLastSibling();` in the `OnBeginDrag` but it only move it to be the first at the parent (the slot) and I want it to be above the other slots so I tried also `transform.parent.SetAsLastSibling();` and at first it looks like it is working but after 2 drags the tank disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a "Canvas" component to your prefab and check "override sorting" and set sort order.  I think I also had to add a graphic raycaster.

Inspector:

[image: inspector]